# Google analytic page views does not match with hit count

Tags: google-analytics

I have 50 banners in my home page. I need to track the impression of each banner. To do this I used the custom variable 5 as page level to track impressions of my banners. I used following code to track custom variable.

```js
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 5, 'impression', '<banner id>', 3]);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action, label]);
```

Now I need to get impression count for each banner using custom variable 5. I used hits metrics to do this. But when I check custom report I could notice that all the event hits are taken to hits count from the page. Because of this the impression count of some banners is higher than page views of particular page. Can any one give me a suggestion to get the impression count from this tracking.

Comment: "all the event hits are taken to hits count from the page" - I do not quite understand what you mean by that, can you clarify ?

Comment: lets say I have another event to track button click. If  user click on that button after tracking the impression to custom variable 5 and then we check the report, the hits count is 2 => 1(impression) + 1(click on button). and @EikePierstorff thanks

Comment: The customVar is applied to all page interactions. I think your best workaround would be to update to Universal Analytics, use a custom metric and send it with the configuration object of the event tracking call (more simply put, with the most recent version of GA you can apply custom metrics to a specific interaction instead of everything that happens on the page. I'm not sure this is possible with the old version, or at least you need to make sure that setCustomVars is pushed after the pageview but before the _trackEvent).

Comment: @EikePierstorff I can't change my tracking to new one because there are lot of dependancies. The setCustomVars is pushed after pageview. Can you please suggest me any other metric or dimension to get impression count. I have an idea to add filter with the action of event which use to track custom variable. I created some reports but the case is I got less count of impressions when I do so.